# Responsive header background image in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

Hello I'm trying to build a website for my brother's company and I'm having a lot of problems to set up a  header with a responsive background image in HTML and CSS, if someone knows what's wrong  would be of great help, this is what I've tried so far

```css
.backimage {
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 500px;
   background-image: url('Images/fuente.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

```html
<header class="backimage">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light">text1</h1>
        <p class="lead">text2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Have you considered using Javascript to read the size of your element (window.innerWidth) and then resizing it accordingly?

Comment: What is the result you expect and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: Considering just what I can see in your code, a `width: 100%` in your `.backimage` will be enough. The background-properties you've set will do the job.

Comment: Hi welcome!  From what I understand, your header will be 500px high?  Since you want the image inside the header and not below the header, it would be good show a sample of what you would like it to look like.  Usually, large background images are placed below the header, that is inside the home page, even if it looks like a header.

Comment: Or are you thinking of a cover page that covers the landing page?

Comment: Hi Pedro, the result that I want is that the image stays the same size for all the different sizes of screens, which is not happening...I change the width to 100% and I got a better result but still, the image gets cut when the screen is desktop size.

Comment: Hi Muge, you might be right I have my navbar as a header and I want this background Image bellow as many web pages usually do(i do not want the image to cover all the landing page), do you think the problem comes from setting the image as a header? or is css problem?